# How big a message can I send via iOS Multipeer Connectivity?

Tags: ios, networking, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

Does anyone have any information about how large messages passed between devices via

```
[MCSession sendData:(NSData *)data
     toPeers:(NSArray *)peerIDs
    withMode:(MCSessionSendDataMode)mode
       error:(NSError **)error];
```

can be? I've been Googling without success. My application needs to send a fairly large (~1-2 MB) packet of information across to the connected device. I intend to use an NSCoding compliant object, which I can pack an unpack on either end. However, I'm unfamiliar with the underlying protocol. Will the session allow such a big object to be passed across? Does it provide packeting behind the scenes?

Any information would be extremely helpful.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: It sounds like that is "implementation details" and not something you can rely on. Have you tried to switch to using stream instead?

Answer (score 1):

As it is clearly mentioned on the documentation, multipeer supports three types of data transfer.

1.Send text using

```
- (BOOL)sendData:(NSData *)data toPeers:(NSArray *)peerIDs withMode:(MCSessionSendDataMode)mode error:(NSError **)error;
```

2.Send local pictures or file using

```
- (NSProgress *)sendResourceAtURL:(NSURL *)resourceURL withName:(NSString *)resourceName toPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

3.Streaming ( of audio) - Using Audio stream and session you can send packets. But the bandwidth limitation of bluetooth is a bottleneck.

I do not think there is a upper limit for file size, while using the second method, using the NSProgress, you can show a loading view too.